# PHPUnit input file issue

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, pear

I know that there has been a lot of talk on PHPUnit issues recently, I have spent the past four days trying to get PHPUnit set up on my Windows 7 computer. I have made sure that I upgraded PEAR so that it is current. When I install PHPUnit I get the following:

```
C:\Users\Marc>pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use PHP extension "curl"
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use PHP extension "dbus"
downloading PHPUnit-3.5.14.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit-3.5.14.tgz (118,697 bytes)
..........................done: 118,697 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit-3.5.14

C:\Users\Marc>
```

So as far as I can tell, all went well... Now when I try to call `phpunit` I get the following issue:

> Cannot open input file C:\server\www\phpunit

Does anyone have an idea how this could be resolved?

Comment: Make sure you have the phpunit.bat file in the system PATH.

Comment: Try calling `phpunit.bat` instead of `phpunit`. Does this work?

Comment: Still the same issue unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out where the phpunit .bat file was installed with

```
$ pear list phpunit/phpunit
```

There will be a line like

```
script    C:\foo\bar\baz\bin\phpunit.bat
```

This directory (`C:\foo\bar\baz\bin\`) needs to be in your `PATH` variable.

Comment: What do you get if you execute the full path?

Comment: Do you have read access to the file, can you edit it? Do you really execute the full path, i.e. "c:\foo\bar\phpunit.bat" (with extension?)

Comment: Yes to all of the above and I dont know why but it is working now anyway??